# Nativescript core OCR plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, nativescript, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to develop an ocr app with the Nativescript plugin:

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-ocr
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-ocr

and it seems that the example doesn't works or I'm doing something wrong. I read something about Firebase ML kit but I have no idea about that and if it works offline (Offline work is a must for me).

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ML_KIT.md

Could be deprecated the first plugin? 
might I use firebase? 
could it use with nativescript core (only js)?
It works offline?
Any idea about how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the OCR plugin is kind of deprecated, not actively maintained anymore.

Firebase ML-Kit is recommended and it has different methods you could use for text recognition, one works on device and another on cloud. Refer the same read me you have linked in your question.

Comment: Ok, I'm very new with nativescript and plugins. I'll try with firebase. Lots of thanks.